# What is the advantage of output_shape argument in Keras Lambda layer

Tags: keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras, keras-layer

```
def euclidean_distance(vects):
x, y = vects
sum_square = K.sum(K.square(x - y), axis=1, keepdims=True)
return K.sqrt(K.maximum(sum_square, K.epsilon()))


def eucl_dist_output_shape(shapes):
    shape1, shape2 = shapes
    return (shape1[0], 1)

input_a = Input(shape=(28,28,), name="left_input")
vect_output_a = base_network(input_a)

input_b = Input(shape=(28,28,), name="right_input")
vect_output_b = base_network(input_b)

# measure the similarity of the two vector outputs
output = Lambda(euclidean_distance, name="output_layer", output_shape=eucl_dist_output_shape)([vect_output_a, vect_output_b])
```

I am passing functor `output_shape=eucl_dist_output_shape` in argument in last line of Lambda Layer but it doesn't do anything. It is only inferring the output from function. Can any body tell me what is the advantage or purpose of `output_shape` argument in Lambda Layer?

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are using TF term frequency for similarity measure for of two
   vector then these points i suggest you for the Lambda Layer?
   1)The main purposes of lambda layer to do some operation on previous
   layer. but do not want to add any trainable weight to it.  2) Lambda
   layer is an easy way to customize a layer to do simple arithmetic.
   Suppose you want to add your own activation function (which is not
   built-in Keras) First you need to define a function that will take
   the output from the previous layer as input and apply a custom
   activation function to it.  Pass this function to the lambda layer.
   Lambda layers are saved by serializing the Python bytecode, subclass
   overriding get-config method and are thus more portable.

Example1

```
from keras.layers import Lambda
from keras import backend as K
# defining a custom non linear function
def activation_relu(inputs):
    return K.maximum(0.,inputs)
# call function using lambda layer
squashed_output = Lambda(activation_relu)(inputs) # where inputs are output from previous layer
```

Example2

```
# add a layer that returns the concatenation
# of the positive part of the input and
# the opposite of the negative part
def antirectifier(x):
    x -= K.mean(x, axis=1, keepdims=True)
    x = K.l2_normalize(x, axis=1)
    pos = K.relu(x)
    neg = K.relu(-x)
    return K.concatenate([pos, neg], axis=1)
model.add(Lambda(antirectifier))
```

Example3
if you want to build a custom layer that computes the element-wise Euclidean distance between two input tensors, I would define the function to compute the value itself, as well as one that returns the output shape from this function.

```
def euclidean_distance(vecs):
   x, y = vecs
   return K.sqrt(K.sum(K.square(x - y), axis=1, keepdims=True))
def euclidean_distance_output_shape(shapes):
    shape1, shape2 = shapes
    return (shape1[0], 1)
Call these functions using the lambda layer 
lhs_input = Input(shape=(VECTOR_SIZE,))
lhs = dense(1024, kernel_initializer="glorot_uniform", activation="relu")(lhs_input)
rhs_input = Input(shape=(VECTOR_SIZE,))
rhs = dense(1024, kernel_initializer="glorot_uniform", activation="relu")(rhs_input)
sim = lambda(euclidean_distance, output_shape=euclidean_distance_output_shape)([lhs, rhs])
```